# Why is Kathy Nicolo sometimes homeless and (later) sometimes staying in a motel?

Tags: character, house-of-sand-and-fog

In *House of Sand and Fog*, Kathy Nicolo is evicted from her house. After that, mostly we see her sleeping in her car and washing up in public bathrooms (while telling people she's staying in a motel). But later, we see her staying in a motel room. Why the change?

Answer (score 1):

I think you got the events mixed up a little. At the beginning, right after Kathy is evicted, she puts all her stuff in a rentable storage garage and then **stays in a motel**. At some point we see the motel owner ask her for payment and saying that her credit card isn't working, to which Kathy apologizes and asks to pay later once she gets her paycheck.

She then **leaves the motel and sleeps in her car for at least one night**. That is also the point where she washes in a public bathroom at the beach promenade (an imagery not too dissimilar to Colonel Behrani having to change in a public bathroom to keep up his wealthy facade).

She then **meets Lester who presumably gets her a motel room** (he even says at some point *"we need to get you some place to stay"*). Later on, after she started an affair with Lester and he *kind of* left his family for Kathy, Lester says that a friend of his has **a cottage where they both can stay together**, which they then do.

And shortly after that the tragic climax starts to unfold, with Kathy trying to commit suicide and staying the night in her/the Behranis' house. Keep in mind that all this happens over not too long a time, since Kathy's mother was about to visit her in about two weeks, which is the date when Kathy needs her house back to keep up her facade.